# Coin flip program that repeats based on "yes" or "no" response

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python and want to create a basic coin flip program that will repeat based on user input.
I was able to create the randomized response for the coin flip but when it asks if I want to repeat it it dosn't generate a new randomized response and instead repeats the same response. how do i get it to restart the program if i input "y".

```
import random
coin = random.randint(0,1)
y = "y"
n = "n"

import sys
def coin_flip():
    if coin == 0:
        print("Heads")
    elif coin == 1:
        print("tails")
    again = input("flip again?('y' or 'n') ")
    if again == y:
        coin_flip()

    else:
        again == n
        print("good bye")
        sys.exit()
coin_flip()
```

Comment: Holy crap! it worked! I had no idea you had to randomize 'coin' twice, thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program keep giving you the same result because you are randomizing the value `coin` variable outside the `coin_flip()` function. Therefore, it is only being randomized once, at the start of the program.

To fix that, simply randomize the `coin` variable value at the start of `coin_flip()` function

```
def coin_flip():
    coin = random.randint(0,1)
    # the rest of the function
```

Comment: The idea is to randomize it every time coin_flip is called, since `random.randint()` only return an integer value. To be more clear about how it works, you can refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be generating the random value within the `coin_flip` function. You only create it at the start of your script, so it is only ever created once.

Move the line `coin = random.randint(0,1)` to the start of the `coin_flip` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you dig around a bit in the [`random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) you will find some interesting utilities that will make things like this very short and pretty. For example

```
random.choice(['Heads', 'Tails']
```

will give you a random heads or tails without all the extra `if/elif` logic. These kind of things will make your code easier to read, understand and maintain. For example you could do something like:

```
import random

while (input("flip again?('y' or 'n') ") == 'y'):
    print(random.choice(['Heads', 'Tails']))
print("good bye")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll definitly have to look into the random module further, the elif statements didn't seem like it wasn't very efficient.